# Matlab: how to concatenate the fields of a structure array?

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I have a structure array in which every value is a number, I would like to concatenate these structures into a single one.

*Example:*

S is structure array and every element has the same structure

```
S(1).a = 1
S(1).b.c = 1
S(1).b.d = 2

S(2).a = 2
S(2).b.c = 3
S(2).b.d = 4
```

cat(S) should be a structure 'CAT' with fields :

```
CAT.a = [1 2]
CAT.b.c = [1 3]
CAT.b.d = [2 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any matlab function to achieve this, so I programmed this function:

```
function out = catStruct(in)
% cat structure field per field

    if isstruct(in)
        for f = fields(in)'
            out.(f{:}) = catStruct([in.(f{:})]);
        end
    else
        out = in;
    end
end
```

If I do CAT = catStruct(S), I get what I want.